# Difference between Public networks and Home networks

Tags: windows, networking

What is the difference exactly between a public network and a private network in windows, i.e., when switching network type from public to home in windows networking center, are there more ports open? Do firewall rules change and how? Does that allow a hacker in my network to perform more actions than before?

Comment: The difference is that on a public network you can assume that some hacker is listening in, whereas on a home network you can assume that some hacker is listening in.

Comment: Why was this question down voted? It's a great question -- one which I've been searching Google trying to find an answer to. +1. That's also a terrible answer, Daniel (no offense, but it is).

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is this:

> Computers on a home network can belong to a homegroup. Network discovery is turned on for home networks, which allows you to see other computers and devices on the network and allows other network users to see your computer.

See: [Windows: Choosing a network location](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/choosing-a-network-location)

In Windows Firewall, there may be different rules for Home and Public networks so you could possibly have more open ports.